# Error while using Adaptive Lasso Function with Boot

Tags: r, glmnet, statistics-bootstrap, lasso-regression

I currently have the below code. The function works when running outside of the boot() function, but when using the boot() function, it provides the error

> Error in t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]] :    number of items to replace is
>   not a multiple of replacement length.

When I use the boot() function, lower values of R allow the function to run properly. Is there something I need to add to my function to ensure that I do not continue to receive this error?

```
    alassoOLS_ydot_n10_fn <- function(data,index){ #index is the bootstrap sample index
      x <- data[index,-1]
      y <- data[index,1]
      cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,nfolds=10, penalty.factor = 1 / abs(best_ridge_coef.ydot.n10)) #alpha=1, lasso
      bestlam <- cv.out$lambda.min #the best lambda chosen by CV
      lasso.mod <- glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,lambda=bestlam, penalty.factor = 1 / abs(best_ridge_coef.ydot.n10))
      coef <- as.vector(coef(lasso.mod))[-1]
      coef_nonzero <- coef != 0
      ls.obj <- lm(y ~x[, coef_nonzero, drop = FALSE])
      ls_coef <- (ls.obj$coefficients)[-1]
      return(ls_coef)
    }

boot(ydot_matrix_n10,alassoOLS_ydot_n10_fn,R=500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the vector returned by `alassoOLS_ydot_n10_fn` is not constant but depends on the number of variables selected by `glmnet`.
I modified your function as follows:

```
alassoOLS_ydot_n10_fn <- function(data,index){ 
  x <- data[index,-1]
  y <- data[index,1]
  cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,nfolds=10) 
  bestlam <- cv.out$lambda.min #the best lambda chosen by CV
  lasso.mod <- glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,lambda=bestlam, penalty.factor = 1/abs(best_ridge_coef.ydot.n10))
  coef <- as.vector(coef(lasso.mod))[-1]
  coef_nonzero <- coef != 0
  ls.obj <- lm(y ~x[, coef_nonzero, drop = FALSE])
  ls_coef <- (ls.obj$coefficients)[-1]
  # Generate a fixed-length vector fo OLS coefficients
  # The coefficients of variables not selected by glmnet were set to zero.
  vect_coef <- rep(0,length(coef_nonzero))
  vect_coef[coef_nonzero] <- ls_coef
  return(vect_coef)
}
```

Now the output is a fixed-length vector of coefficients.
I set to 0 the coefficients of the covariates not selected by glmnet.
(I don't know if this is correct from a statistical point of view in your investigation.
My aim is only to show the source of the error message given by `boot`.)
Now `boot` works with no errors. See the following example.

```
set.seed(1)
ydot_matrix_n10 <- matrix(runif(1000), ncol=10)
best_ridge_coef.ydot.n10 <- 10
boot(ydot_matrix_n10,alassoOLS_ydot_n10_fn,R=50)
```

The output is reported below.

```
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP

Bootstrap Statistics :
       original       bias    std. error
t1*  0.00000000 -0.002330197  0.02319543
t2*  0.13530886 -0.001906712  0.09889174
t3* -0.19509877 -0.013020365  0.07251921
t4* -0.01954785  0.015227018  0.09184750
t5*  0.05600451  0.008896392  0.08729263
t6*  0.12978757 -0.013795860  0.11320119
t7*  0.06525111 -0.007208380  0.09703813
t8*  0.09368079 -0.017343037  0.08947958
t9* -0.09518469 -0.003352512  0.08575450
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @statsguy27 Nice to help you! Please, accept and upvote my answer. Thank you.